# Am I expected to add more or further thoughts following indeed?

Tags: american-english, british-english, conversation

Is it proper to reply “Indeed!” to agree with someone on some opinion?

Am I expected to add more or further thoughts following indeed? (I remember seeing such advice somewhere, and can't find it. But I like using just 'Indeed!' in place of just 'Yes!' ) Or is that not necessary? Are the answers the same or different in American and British English?

Comment: You can make short utterances of agreement, e.g. 'Right on!', 'Right', 'Yes!', 'Indeed!' etc, and you may wish to add further words, or you may not. Either is acceptable.

Comment: Indeed and yes are the same but indeed is snotty unless used with peers.

Comment: @Lambie what is snotty about it?

Comment: Things that aren't in dictionaries about language and usage.